# Plot only selected points of a time series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, time-series

I have a univariate time series structured as well:

```
data = [15, 5, 7, 9, 10, 23, 4, 6]
```

And a list of score of the values inside the list, structured as well:

```
score = [0.3, 0.6, 0.1, 0.8, 0.4, 0.7, 0.3, 0.1]
```

I also have a threshold `t = 0.5`

From this, I created a dataframe with two columns, where in the first one I have the value and in the second one I have **True** if it is an anomaly (which means it has a score a score `> t`) and **False** if it is not (score`< t`). The structure is this:

```
values | anomalies
  15   |   False
  5    |   True
  7    |   False
  9    |   True
  10   |   False
  23   |   True
  4    |   False
  6    |   False
```

What I wanna do is plot the values with `anomalies==True` in a color, and the values with `anomalies==False` in another color. I tried to plot the normal values and then overlap them with the anomalies ones, as you can see in this fragment of code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25,5)) 
ax1=plt.subplot(121)
sns.lineplot(data=df['values'], ax=ax1) # plot normal time series plot
sns.lineplot(data=df['values'][(df['anomalies'] == True )], color='red', ax=ax1)
```

But the result is the one in the following figure, where the red points are linked even if they should be separated:
[image]

How can I solve it?

Comment: The problem is you have points and you want to set color to lines. From a normal point to an abnormal point which is the color (and same from abnormal point to normal point)?

Comment: Other point: True or False when score == t?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **markevery** argument to the plot function as described [here] ([Highlighting arbitrary points in a matplotlib plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42872212/highlighting-arbitrary-points-in-a-matplotlib-plot/56703148)). Then you can set the **markerface** to your liking.

```py
  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import seaborn as sns
  sns.set()
  data = [15, 5, 7, 9, 10, 23, 4, 6]
  score = [0.3, 0.6, 0.1, 0.8, 0.4, 0.7, 0.3, 0.1]
  df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['values'])
  df['score'] = score
  plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
  plt.plot(df.index, df['values'], '-go', markevery=np.where(df.score > 0.5, True, False), markerfacecolor='b')
  plt.xlabel('Index')
  plt.ylabel('Values')
  plt.title('Anomalies Plot')
```

It will look something like this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzEf5.png)

you can achieve similar result using **seaborn** by replacing

```py
plt.plot(df.index, df['values'], '-go', markevery=np.where(df.score > 0.5, True, False), markerfacecolor='b')
```

with

```py
sns.scatterplot(x=df.index,y=df['values'], hue=df.score>0.5)
sns.lineplot(x=df.index,y=df['values'])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a dataframe first:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['data','score','anomalies'])
```

then:

```
df.loc[df[score]>t,'anomalies'] = 'True'
```

for your first part of the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use `LineCollection`:

```
# Imports
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

# Data
data = [15, 5, 7, 9, 10, 23, 4, 6]
score = [0.3, 0.6, 0.1, 0.8, 0.4, 0.7, 0.3, 0.1]
t = 0.5

# Create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'values': data, 'score': score})
df['anomalies'] = df['score'] > t

# Build colored segments
x = zip(range(len(df)), range(1, len(df)))
y = zip(df['values'], df['values'][1:])
lines = [[(x0, x1), (y0, y1)] for (x0, y0), (x1, y1) in zip(x, y)]
linecolors = df['anomalies'].replace({True: 'red', False: 'blue'})
segments = LineCollection(lines, colors=linecolors)

# Plot chart
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_collection(segments)

# Limits are not set automatically when using LineCollection
ax.set_xlim(0, len(df))
ax.set_ylim(0, df['values'].max()+1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   values  score  anomalies
0      15    0.3      False
1       5    0.6       True
2       7    0.1      False
3       9    0.8       True
4      10    0.4      False
5      23    0.7       True
6       4    0.3      False
7       6    0.1      False
```

[image: LineCollection]